# rails nested_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic, nested-attributes

I want to create a comment form at the bottom of a blog entry.  The problem is that it doesn't save the blog_id so while the comment is created, it isn't assigned a blog_id.  I thought that by having this line:

```
@new_comment = @blog.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

that it would work but it doesnt.  This is what I have:

blog#show

```
def show
 @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
 @new_comment = @blog.comments.build(params[:comment])
end
```

blog#form

```
...
<%= semantic_form_for @new_comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :content, :label => "Comment", :input_html => { :rows => 6, :class => "xxlarge" } %>
<div class="pull-right"><%= f.commit_button :button_html => {:class => "primary"}, :label => "Submit" %></div>
<% end %>
```

blog.rb

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

comments controller

```
  def create
@comment = @blog.comments.build(params[:comment])
if @comment.save
  redirect_back_or show_blog_path(@blog)
else
  redirect_to show_blog_path(@blog)
end
end
```

**EDIT:**

I nested the form inside the @blog by doing:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @blog do |f| %>
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :comments do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.input :name %>
   <%= ff.input :content, :label => "Comment", :input_html => { :rows => 6, :class => "xxlarge" } %>
<% end %>    
<div class="pull-right"><%= f.commit_button :button_html => {:class => "primary"}, :label => "Submit" %></div>
<% end %>
```

and changed the blogs#show to:

```
@blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
@blog.comments.build
@comments = Comment.where(:blog_id => @blog.id)
```

Everything works fine, but now after I submit the comment, the comment shows up twice.  It shows up in the comments section where it is supposed to and it also shows up as a prepopulated comments form on top of a new comments form.  So you see the content of the blog, the prepopulated comment form that I just submitted, a new comments form, and the comment in the display comments section.

I don't know what that it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not referencing the parent object in your form. Yes, you have initialised `@new_comment` which references the current `@blog`, but the comment form does not specify this. If you inspect the params passed to create action of comments controller, you are most likely to find no `bold_id` being passed.

Try doing

```
f.hidden :blog
```

in the comment form.

Or, if you do not wish to have a hidden field as such, then you can have a nested form as

```
semantic_form_for [@blog, @new_comment] do |f|
```

But, this requires your routes file to have paths for comments to be nested under blogs, something as(lets take only the create action for now)

```
resources :blogs do
   resources :comments, :only => [:create]
end
```

This is required as the form's post is directed to blog_comments_path.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT** : This is how I suggest implementing it (ymmv, so, please be clear if it satisfies your needs) -

`blogs#show` as :

```
@blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
@now_comment = @blog.comments.build 
@comments = @blog.comments # existing comments u might wanna show below the post
```

The form as :

```
= semantic_form_for [@blog, @new_comment] do |f|
   # input for name and content
```

Routes - nested as shown above

`comments#create` as : (blog_id is passed as params too. So, you can find the blog and build a comment based on comment params for that blog and then save it)

```
@blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
@comment = @blog.comments.new(params[:comment])
@comment.save
```

Comment: i don't want to add the hidden field.  I nested the form the way I am used to.  (not sure what the different between the way I do it and the way you do it is). but see my edit above with the new issue from that. thanks.

Comment: The prepopulated comment forms are due to @comments variable. The `semantic_fields_for' is essentially doing a loop on all the comments(i.e. existing comments of the blog and a new comment being instantiated by @blog.comments.build line) and displaying each in the form.

Comment: p.s. : Is the above (after your edit) working properly ? The form has semantic_form_for `@blog` and it accepts nested attributes for each of its comments, how come is the form now submitted to create action of comments controller. The form now acts as an edit form for `@blog`, hence submits to update action of blogs controller.
That is where the comments are being created(or the blog is being updated thereby creating comments since it accepts nested attributes for them).

Comment: see the update - that way we won't need the accepts nested attributes, since we are not creating/updating comments of a blog when creating/updating the blog. Or, as your current edit, if you intend to use it, and create/update comments by creating/updating its parent(i.e. blog), the create and update action for comments controller can be removed, unless you intend to create/edit individual comment.
The latter is indeed a poor implementation, since, we are updating a blog if we update the comment too. Its better to simply have has_may comments for blog, and not use the nested attributes.

Comment: I tried it your way and it didn't work either.  It tells me it can't find an id = blog_id.  It also doesn't recognize comments from the line `@blog.comments.new(params[:comment])`.  Also, did you say the way I did it after my edit is bad implementation because i am using nested attributes?

Comment: can you post the params passed to comments#create ? No, I did not mean using nested attributes is bad. What I meant is, if the blog gets updated when updating a comment or in other words, if updating a single comment leads to blogs#update where it updates the corresponding blog and that comment, then its not a good implementation. Why bother the blog about one of its comments, right ?